# perl compare all combinations in hash

Tags: perl, hash, combinations

I need to compare hash elements and pick out all different pairs.
To simplify,

```
my %hash = (
      'row1' => { 'id_a' => 0.5 , 'id_b' => 0.5, 'id_c' => 0.5, 'id_d'=> 0.5 },
      'row2' => { 'id_a' => 0.5 , 'id_b' => 0  , 'id_c' => 0.5, 'id_d'=> 0.5 }
      'row3' => { 'id_a' => 0.5 , 'id_b' => 0.5, 'id_c' => 0  , 'id_d'=> 0   }
      ... 50 more rows of 'rowx'
```

);

Desired in/outputs:
Input : %hash
Outputs : All pair that differ in value : 
row2-id_a/id_b, row2-id_b/id_c, row2-id_b/id_d. 
row3-id_a/id_c, row3-id_a/id_d, row3-id_b/id_c, row3-id_b/id_d.

Comparison will be made within a row for all possible pairs.

```
while( ($k, $v) = each %hash ) {
   # foreach my $rowkey (sort keys %{$hash{$k}}) {
   #   if ($hash{$rowkey}->{$current key} == $hash{$rowkey}->{$next key} ) {
   #   good to go }
   #   else { do something }
}
```

**This pseudo code will only compare adjacent element.  I need to compare all combination.  Thanks.**

Comment: Your comparison algorithm requirement is unclear, please provide "pseudo" code or a better illustration

Comment: can you give more rows, and wanted output?

Comment: @mpapec I added at the bottom.

Comment: do you want the output to show all differences for a row or just the first difference found?

Comment: @ysth all differences for a row.

Answer (score 2):

```
for my $row ( sort keys %hash ) {
    if ( $hash{$row}{'id_a'} != $hash{$row}{'id_b'} || $hash{$row}{'id_b'} != $hash{$row}{'id_c'} ) {
        print "row $row has different values\n";
    }
}
```

To check an arbitrary number of values:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
...
    if ( uniq( values %{ $hash{$row} } ) > 1 ) {
        print "row $row has different values\n";
    }
```

(though this will check for unique strings, a slightly weaker check than checking for unique numbers.)

Comment: Thanks but I have large number of keys not just three in the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
my %hash = (
      'row1' => { 'id_a' => 0.5 , 'id_b' => 0.5, 'id_c' => 0.5 },
      'row2' => { 'id_a' => 0.5 , 'id_b' => 0.0, 'id_c' => 0.5 }
);

for my $k (sort keys %hash) {

  my @rkeys = sort keys %{ $hash{$k} };

  for my $rk (0 .. $#rkeys-1) {
    my ($current, $next) = @rkeys[$rk, $rk+1];

    if ($hash{$k}{$current} != $hash{$k}{$next}) {
      print "difference at : $k-$current/$next\n";
    }
    # else {}
  }
}
```

output

```
difference at : row2-id_a/id_b
difference at : row2-id_b/id_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to mpapec's answer,

```
foreach my $layer1 (sort keys %hash){
    print "$layer1: \n";
    my @layer2 = sort keys %{$hash{$layer1}};
    print "@layer2\n";
    #loop pst elements.  All combinations.  Outer loop: increment reference point.  Inner loop: compare values from ref to end of hash row.
    for my $rk (0 .. $#layer2-1) {
            #Get current key.
            my $current = @layer2[$rk];
            #Increment from reference point to the end of the hash row.
            for my $rk_inc ($rk+1 .. $#layer2) {
            #Get hash key for comparison.
            my $next = @layer2[$rk_inc];
                    print "Comparing : " . $current . " ". $next. " \n";
                    if ( ( $hash{$layer1}{$current} != $hash{$layer1}{$next} ) ) { 
                    ## Do something here.
                    }
            }
     }
}
```